# Flex 4.5 arrange gui components

Tags: apache-flex, user-interface

I am using IFrame and adding it dynamically, and it hides a new Alert.show and a previously made TitleWindow.

How do I arrange it to go back or to make that Alert or window on  top of all ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're doing, and possibly show some code?

Comment: making web app using flex-iframe from google code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't, as they are parents of different view heirachy's.

The Popup is managed by the SWF, and is a child of the application's display list.
The IFrame is managed by the HTML, and is a child of the DOM.

ie:

```
 + HTML Page
 |
 |
 +---IFrame
 |
 +---SWF (Flex Application)
      |
      +--- System Manager
      |       |
      |       +---- Popup's // <---- Your Popup is here
      +--- Application
```

Unfortunately there's no solution here that I'm aware of, you'll need to either display the popup within the IFrame, or remove the IFrame to show the popup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using the mx:HTML component to display some HTML. I got the same issue in my project, IFrame objects always display on top of everything.

An efficient workaround is to draw the hide the HTML component and display a bitmap snapshot of it instead. That way, the Alert or any popup will display on top of it.

Here's how I did it

```
    private var _snapshotImage:Bitmap;

    private function toggleSnapshotMode(htmlVisible:Boolean):void
    {
        if(!htmlVisible)
        {
            var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(htmlLoader.width,htmlLoader.height,false);
            bitmapData.draw(htmlLoader,null,null,null,null,true);
            _snapshotImage = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
            _snapshotImage.x = htmlLoader.x;
            _snapshotImage.y = htmlLoader.y;
            html.addChildAt(_snapshotImage,0);
        }
        else
        {
            html.removeChild(_snapshotImage);
        }

        html.htmlLoader.visible = htmlVisible;
    }
```

Comment: Neat trick, but HTML is AIR only, not available in a browser based app (oh, the irony).  I assume that the OP is talking about a browser app.

Comment: Well you can use this technique with any component in fact. Just replace "htmlLoader" with your component and "html" with it's parent (like s:Group)

Comment: Not with an iFrame.  That trick assumes that the content is being rendered by the Flash Player.  When you use an IFrame, the content is rendered by the browser, and positioned to appear it's part of the application.  Trying to get the Flash Player to capture it's bitmap data wouldn't work.